# Matched size random samples from hive table

Tags: hive

I have a hive table `activity` with columns `userid`, `itemid`, and `rating`, with possible ratings of 1 and 0, in which there are many more positive ratings (1s) then negative ratings (0s). I need to extract a sample with approximately equal numbers of positive and negative ratings. I need this sample to be as large as possible, so want to sample all the negative rating rows, plus an equal number of positive rating rows, sampled *randomly*.

For example, let's say we have 100k total rows in the table, 75k with rating=1, and 25k with rating=0. What is the most efficient query (or queries) to return all 25k rows with rating=0 and 25k randomly sampled rows with rating=1? The actual tables are much larger, so speed is important here.

Comment: This has to be a single query or can you programmatically run few queries and use the results of q1 in q2 etc. ?

Comment: Single query is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in advance that negatives are the limiting factor, you can get the exact number with the first query (let's say N).
Then you can get the entire sample with (hardcode N here)

```
select * from
(
  select * from activity where rating=1 order by rand() limit N
  union all
  select * from activity where rating=0  
) all_sample
order by rand() limit 2N
```

the last order may not be necessary, depending on your need.

Answer (score 3):

As is suggested here (http://www.joefkelley.com/736/), rand() will only randomize across a single reducer. If you have a skew of data in your dataset (e.g., if you don't distribute by the key you are randomizing) you may see skewed results.

First be sure you are using DISTRIBUTE BY your key, then use rand() with limit to return N values.

Comment: just adding query here for clarity:

select * from my_table
distribute by rand()
sort by rand()
limit 10000;

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of classes, you can use the following query to get samples across all the classes without writing the query multiple times:

```
select * from 
    (select userid, item_id, rating, 
    row_number() over(partition by rating  order by rand()) as rn 
    from activity
    ) a 
where rn <= x
```

x can be whatever the count you want each class to be of.